# Auto increment a column based on another column avoiding race condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, triggers, race-condition, before-save

Lets say I have a model Document.

```
Document
document_id -> int
client_id -> int
```

I want the document id to be auto incremented based on the client id avoiding a race condition. I have an unique constraint on document_id, client_id.

```
 client_id   document_id 
 1           1
 1           2
 2           1
 1           3
```

Approach 1: Right now, Im setting the document id on before_create callback but it leads to race condition and sets the same value when multiple documents are received for the same client at the same time.

before_create :set_identifier
def set_identifier
self.document_id = client.documents.maximum(:document_id).next
end

This raises the below error when 2 documents are created at the same time.

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
> PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint

Approach 2: Tried using DB triggers on postgresql. It works fine. But the only problem is that, the updated value doesn't reflect initially on the assigned variable. I need to do a force reload on the variable.

DB Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION set_document_identifier()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE
max_identifier INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT MAX(document_id) INTO max_identifier
  FROM documents
  WHERE client_id = NEW.client_id;
IF max_identifier IS NULL THEN
    max_identifier := 1;
END IF;
NEW.document_id := max_identifier;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

DB Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_trigger_documents
BEFORE INSERT ON documents
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION set_document_identifier();
```

Rails:

```
doc = Document.create!(client_id: 1)
doc.document_id -> nil
doc.reload.document_id -> 1
```

Is there any other possible OTB solution which rails provide or a workaround that can be done on the triggers so that the value is set before the transaction commit?

Comment: By *"document id to be auto incremented based on the client id"* do you meant you want to have a separate sequence of `document_id`'s for each `client_id`? Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77855222/postgresql-trigger-problem-with-unique-key-constraint/77856295#77856295) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77509146/generate-sequential-and-distinct-order-numbers-for-vendors-in-postgresql/77510834#77510834)?

Comment: @Zegarek Yes, separate sequence is achieved through triggers. But the value is not  being reloaded after the record is persisted in Rails.
This is answered here. But looks like an inefficient way since it triggers one more query after create to fetch the details.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11422116/4623420

Comment: You can do this without triggers. See the [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77573225/incrementing-sequential-number-on-inserts/77573342#77573342).

Comment: @TheImpaler [That example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77573225/incrementing-sequential-number-on-inserts/77573342#77573342) "does away without triggers" because it wants all users to each time manually handle everything you'd want that trigger for.

Comment: @Zegarek True .

Answer (score 0):

You obviously can't have unique incrementing values per `client_id` and also have multiple users generating their own next value concurrently. That's just how the universe works.

The simplest method to deal with this is (as you discovered) to have a single point where this is done - in the database.

You should also either (a) lock appropriately to prevent concurrent inserts or (b) expect duplicate key errors and handle them.

Answer (score 0):

1. If what you showed is really how your trigger works, you forgot to increment. This would set first `document_id` to `1`. Next insert for the same `client_id` finds only that `1`, which makes it `max()` and that insert will also use that same value of `1`. You'd keep getting `1`'s all the time: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/J_XyMigx). If you add the `+1`, it'll *kind of work*: [demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/SVbv-6vc).

   ```sql
   SELECT MAX(document_id)+1 INTO max_identifier
   ```
2. Even if you fix that, when you insert multiple documents for a single `client_id` concurrently, they will all find and use the same `max()`, resulting in two different documents with the same id.
3. > a workaround that can be done on the triggers so that the value is set before the transaction commit

   The value *is* set before the transaction commit but if your app the `returning` clause on the `insert` issued by Rails doesn't include the value you were hoping to generate, you need to tell it to go find it afterwards based on the record's unique id that it does always have.

If you instead use generated, seed-based sequences like in the [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77856295/5298879) I mentioned, it'll work with concurrent inserts too: [demo3](https://dbfiddle.uk/4gRXbKcq)

```sql
create function seeded_sequence_nextval(seed text, 
                                        owner_table regclass default null,
                                        owner_column text default 'ctid') 
returns int as $f$
declare sequence_name text:=concat_ws('__','seeded_sequence',
                                           owner_table,
                                           owner_column,
                                           seed);
begin execute format('create sequence if not exists %I owned by %s;',
                     sequence_name,
                     case when owner_table is null then 'none'
                          else format('%s.%I',owner_table,owner_column)
                     end);
      return nextval(format('%I',sequence_name));
end $f$ language plpgsql;
```

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION set_document_identifier()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $f$
BEGIN
SELECT seeded_sequence_nextval(NEW.client_id::text,'documents','document_id')
  INTO NEW.document_id;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$f$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_trigger_documents BEFORE INSERT ON documents
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION set_document_identifier();
```

There's a [potential caveat](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23889619/5298879) to spawning many sequences but it [might not necessarily](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76573035/5298879) be a thing.

Comment: I think that creating one database sequence on the fly, per client, could be a brittle solution. It's a lot easier to have a single "last_values_table" and using a lock when generating a new sequential value.

Comment: @TheImpaler I think the words you were looking for were *simple, fast, robust, declarative, automatic* :) I'd be interested in a description (a demonstration would be even more welcome) of the *brittleness* you suspect this of - I don't meant the particular implementation since that could use proper schema qualification, additional metadata table, sanitizing and a pass-through for sequence options, etc. I mean I'd be interested to know what you find *wrong* about the idea of seeded/generated sequences, create-upon-nextval.

Comment: As to the "last_values_table": in MySQL it *is* a lot easier, because it's the only option - MySQL doesn't have `sequence`s. You didn't offer and I didn't notice any benefit of emulating (mimicking, mocking) sequences like that in PostgreSQL, where they're built in, out of the box, with a bunch of functions, options, performance and metadata, (fraction of) which you propose to re-implement oneself (e.g. the find-lock-increment-use-release is attempting to `nextval()`, manually).

Comment: An application with no bugs will dispose of unused sequences as needed. However, it's very common for the second, third developer that works in a project not to be aware of the details, and it becomes easier to get lingering sequences, not used by anyone anymore. The management of these sequences can be tricky.

Comment: Your example requires ***more*** *awaraness of the details* from the dev, doing the job a trigger would normally do, and all sequences would normally handle. I'd expect more orphaned/overlooked things in that scenario. These here all spawn automatically and get tied to the table(+column) the same way underlying serial/identity/default/generated sources are. In both your case and mine, removing `client.id` "owning" the individual sequence, orphans it. Their cleanup looks the same for both: scan for removed clients, `delete` corresponding "last_values_table" row or `drop` corresponding sequence.

Comment: If you let devs do sequences with `last_values_table`, expect lingering `last_values_table`s everywhere - there's no link to what they generate numbers for. A partial solution is to make `last_values_table.client_id` PK become a mirror FK of `documents.client_id`, linking it to common source `client.id` - it indirectly communicates dependency and enables `on delete cascade` from a client to their corresponding "sequence row". Regular `sequence`s can't be tied to *rows* but a `trigger t after delete or update on "client"` can handle the individual cascades based on the client/seed in the name.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot encapsulate the document creation logic in a service object that receives an array of documents regardless of whether it is a single document?

With that approach, you can obtain the id of the first document from the model and then increment it one by one in your service to save the ID without having problems in the records.

```
class Creator
  def initialize(documents)
     @user
     @documents
  end
  
  def call
     document_id = Document.id_per_user(user)
     documents.each do |doc|
       doc.id = document_id
       doc.create!
       
       document_id += 1
     end
  end
end
```

Another approach is use the callback as in your first solution and then rescue the ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique, then:

```
document_id += 1
retry
```